# How to bind 2 GET methods in Spring MVC and distinguish using @RequestMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 different method, both have same url, but different set of incoming params, can I properly map them using @RequestMapping?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView methodA (
    @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String param1,
    @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2) {

    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView methodB (
    @RequestParam(value = "array", required = false) String[] array) {

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can narrow a mapped request based on the existance or non-existance of the request parameters, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.GET, params={"!param1", "!param2"})
public ModelAndView methodB (
        @RequestParam(value = "array", required = false) String[] array) {

    return null;
}
```

will mapp to the methodB only when there is no `param1` or `param2` in the request and will give an info to the framework how to distinguish between the two mappings, so you won't get any errors at startup